# Counting Heroku errors

Tags: performance, heroku

My (rails) application hosted on Heroku sometimes produces errors outside of the application stack.

These are reported as H12 or H18 errors by the heroku router, and sometimes database connection timeouts somewhere high up in the Rails stack.

They're indicators of performance problems, and the action that's failing is often not the one that has the performance problem.  And there isn't a single fix.

So I'd like to be able to count how frequently these errors come up, and graph them, so I can watch the graph trend in the right direction.

I've been doing this kind of ad-hoc by searching and parsing the logs.  This is fine as far as it goes, but as I drift towards graphing the data I suspect I'm starting to reinvent the wheel.

Ideally I'd have an add-on to my Heroku application that would track these things and show me graphs over time.

Does such a thing exist?  Is there something halfway to this point where I can carry it the rest of the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with papertrail and librato.

Papertrail consumes your logs and lets you save searches. Searches can also be set as alerts, which can report how many instances occurred to librato as a metric.

See here: http://support.metrics.librato.com/knowledgebase/articles/30296-papertrail-integration

Answer (score 0):

You should look at some of the Logging addons - LogEntries and Papertrail should be able to do this for you.

Comment: I use papertrail, and they have a nice feature where you save a search and they email you reports on matches to that search.  This gives me some coarse idea of frequency.  I'm looking for more precise graphing of errors over time.